# How to get image from url and save it in mysql as BLOB ? php

Tags: php, mysql

Clear form the question ,I'm using php for my backend , I want to get content of url image then insert it in mysql as BLOB type ? how to do this ?

I tried this code :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "111";
$dbname = "111";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$data = file_get_contents("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3ODc2ODc0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjgzNjc3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg");


    $sql =  "UPDATE employee SET realPhoto='".$data."' WHERE id= 2";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo  ("true");

 } else {

echo  ("false");
 }

?>
```

I want something like this without using Imagick class , how ?

Comment: You need to show us what have you tried.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Don't escape binary image data...  you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries...

Comment: Use `$data = file_get_contents($imageUrl);` instead.

Comment: @magnuseriksson I tried , look at my update ,

Comment: @magnuseriksson I get `false`

Comment: file_get_contents must have permission: allow_url_fopen in your php.ini, and you could bypass this by using curl instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, file_get_contents($filename))."')"
```

Comment: I would not recommend escaping binary image data. Not if you want the image to still work, anyway.

Comment: If you want to insert binary data into a string column (such as a BLOB column), you should represent certain characters by escape sequences. Backslash (“\”) and the quote character used to quote the string must be escaped. In certain client environments, it may also be necessary to escape NUL or Control+Z. The mysql client truncates quoted strings containing NUL characters if they are not escaped, and Control+Z may be taken for END-OF-FILE on Windows if not escaped. For the escape sequences that represent each of these characters, see Table 10.1, “Special Character Escape Sequences”.

Comment: what is `$link` and `$filename` in your answer ?

Comment: `$link` is connection to database result of function `mysqli_connect`, `$filename` is string which contain path to file or url adress of image you want to insert into DB

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_put_contents`

```
file_put_contents($imgBlob, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: How would `file_put_contents()` save it to his database?

Comment: Its enough to guide anyone to understand how he can save it from there to a database. He wants to save the url content to DB